# PHP code fails to produce proper json response when enclosed in a function

Tags: php, wordpress, function, variables, scope

This code works fine. I am able to get a page of populated JSON that is written to a cache file:

```
$test_tag = "afro";

$page = 1;
$images = array();
$tags = array();
$imagetype = 'Recent Cuts';
$per_page = 60;
$orderby_view = FALSE;

$tags2 = $test_tag;
$tags = explode(',', $test_tag);
if( count($tags) == 1 && strlen($tags[0]) == 0 ) $tags = array();
$tag_url = urlencode($tags2);

$cachename = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/cache-fp/' . $imagetype . '-' . $per_page . '-' . $page . '-' . ($orderby_view ? 'by_view' : 'by_date') . $tag_url . '.json';

    $detailurl = get_option('image_detail_url');
    $detailurl .= (strstr($detailurl, '?') === FALSE ? '?' : '&');
    $json = array();
    $images = array();
    $posts = get_pix($imagetype, array('per_page' => $per_page, 'page' => $page, 'tags' => $tags), $orderby_view);


    foreach( $posts['attachments'] as $ii => $post ) {
        $ta = array();
        $meta = array();
        $imagesrclight2 = array();
        // BWP - Theater mode
        $ta['detail_url'] = $detailurl . 'uid=' . $post->post_author . '&img_id=' . $post->ID . '&theater';


        $meta = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'image_tag', false);
        $ta['image_tags'] = implode(' ', $meta);


        $ta['attachment_image'] = wp_get_attachment_image($image->ID, 'thumbnail'); 
        $imagesrclight2 = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image->ID, array(150, 150)); 
        $ta['attachment_image_src'] = rawurlencode($imagesrclight2[0]);


        $images[] = $ta;
    }

    file_put_contents($cachename, json_encode($images));
```

BUT when I enclose this code in a function, the JSON response is written to file as before, but it is just an empty skeleton with no data. All I am doing is enclosing the above code inside a new function, passing in the top `$test_tag` variable and executing the function. I also add an `echo()` which verifies that `$test_tag` is passed in. For some reason, it appears that the `get_pix()` and/or `get_option()` functions are failing to get the data even though $test_tag is the same in both tests.

```
$test_tag = "afro";
newFunction($test_tag);

function newFunction($test_tag) {

$page = 1;
$images = array();
$tags = array();
$imagetype = 'Recent Cuts';
$per_page = 60;
$orderby_view = FALSE;


echo $test_tag; //this works, so var is passed in properly

$tags2 = $test_tag;
$tags = explode(',', $test_tag);
if( count($tags) == 1 && strlen($tags[0]) == 0 ) $tags = array();
$tag_url = urlencode($tags2);

$cachename = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/cache-fp/' . $imagetype . '-' . $per_page . '-' . $page . '-' . ($orderby_view ? 'by_view' : 'by_date') . $tag_url . '.json';

    $detailurl = get_option('image_detail_url');
    $detailurl .= (strstr($detailurl, '?') === FALSE ? '?' : '&');
    $json = array();
    $images = array();
    $posts = get_pix($imagetype, array('per_page' => $per_page, 'page' => $page, 'tags' => $tags), $orderby_view);


    foreach( $posts['attachments'] as $ii => $post ) {
        $ta = array();
        $meta = array();
        $imagesrclight2 = array();
        // BWP - Theater mode
        $ta['detail_url'] = $detailurl . 'uid=' . $post->post_author . '&img_id=' . $post->ID . '&theater';


        $meta = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'image_tag', false);
        $ta['image_tags'] = implode(' ', $meta);


        $ta['attachment_image'] = wp_get_attachment_image($image->ID, 'thumbnail'); 
        $imagesrclight2 = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image->ID, array(150, 150)); 
        $ta['attachment_image_src'] = rawurlencode($imagesrclight2[0]);


        $images[] = $ta;
    }

    file_put_contents($cachename, json_encode($images));
}
```

I really hope I am missing something simple. I can only suspect that inside `newFunction()`, `$test_tag` is somehow treated differently even though echo() proves it has the same value.

Comment: "it appears", "and/or"?  Could you verify that?  It sounds like you simply need to do a bit more debugging to identify the point of failure.

Comment: Do any of the functions you call make use of "global" variables? All the variables except for `$test_tag` are no longer global, so they won't be seen by the other functions.

Comment: If the problem is apparently in `get_pix` or `get_option`, why haven't you included their definitions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The wordpress function get_the_ID() would not work inside of the function, returning a null value. Instead I used $post->ID, which is identical, and it worked. I don't like Wordpress.

Comment: Many of those WordPress template functions (like `get_the_ID()`) are built for use within "the loop".

Comment: I was inside "The Loop" inside my function. Which is why it worked in the original code in the first place.

Comment: Some weird Wordpress stuff going on. I spent the last 2 days trying to figure it out and now that it works, I just don't have time to investigate it any further. I don't like Wordpress.